# Accessing PHP Environment variables in php-fpm pool conf file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php

I am using apache Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
I am using php5-fpm 
I am using PHP version 5.3.10

My issue is the following:
When a request is made to index.php, PHP Environment variables defined in my .htaccess file are being prefixed with "REDIRECT_" due to php-fpm acting as a redirect. For example, the variable _SERVER["HTACCESS_SET_VARIABLE"] is being renamed to _SERVER["REDIRECT_HTACCESS_SET_VARIABLE"]

I need to be able to set _SERVER["HTACCESS_SET_VARIABLE"] in the php-fpm.conf file. Obviously static variables can be set as suck

```
env[HTACCESS_SET_VARIABLE] = Some static text here
```

However, I want to be able to dynamically set the value of env[HTACCESS_SET_VARIABLE] to be whatever the value of  _SERVER["REDIRECT_HTACCESS_SET_VARIABLE"] is. I have tried using $REDIRECT_HTACCESS_SET_VARIABLE, $_SERVER["REDIRECT_HTACCESS_SET_VARIABLE"] and ever other $ prefixed variable I can think of.

Does anyone know how to access the PHP environment variables in php-fpm.conf?

Thank you for your time.